# Python - How can I build a correct statement?

Tags: python

Im fresh here and with Python, I have this challenge in python 3.
1 - Check if the internet connection is working fine.
2 - If condition one is true call a service
3 - Repeat

This code is uded to check if the ping is working:

```
import os
hostname = ('https://fmolinaclouds0000000000trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com/demoApp/demo0
1/app02/SHIOT_02/services/putSensorReading.xsjs?id=TEST&value=999')

while true:
response = os.system('ping -c 1 ' + hostname)

#and then check the response...
if response == 0:
   print('is up!')
else:
print('is down!')
```

This is the code that call the service:

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
sense = SenseHat()
import requests
import time

temp = sense.temp
payload_temp = {'id': 'TEMP', 'value': sense.get_temperature()}
payload_press = {'id': 'PRESS', 'value': sense.get_pressure()}
payload_humit = {'id': 'HUMIT', 'value': sense.get_humidity()}
payload_ts = {'id': 'TS', 'value': time.time()}

while True:

# Wait for 60 seconds


    temp = sense.temp
    requests.get('https://fmolinaclouds0008215086trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com/demoApp/demo01/app02/SHIOT_02/services/putSensorReading.xsjs', params=payload_temp)
    r = requests.get('https://fmolinaclouds0008215086trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com/demoApp/demo01/app02/SHIOT_02/services/putSensorReading.xsjs', params=payload_press)
    r = requests.get('https://fmolinaclouds0008215086trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com/demoApp/demo01/app02/SHIOT_02/services/putSensorReading.xsjs', params=payload_humit)

    print(payload_temp)
    print(payload_press)
    print(payload_humit)
#    print(payload_ts)


time.sleep(60)
```

So, how can put all of this together?

Comment: @PeterWood sure it will if he is passing '-c1' a count of 1 ping.

Comment: `https://.../` is not an hostname, it's an URL. You can fetch it, but you can't ping it. FWIW, most people ping DNS servers like `8.8.8.8` instead of web servers

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to define a function and then call that from your main program, e.g

```
def check_internet(hostname):
    return os.system("ping --count 1 " + hostname) == 0:
# step 1
internet_okay = check_internet("localhost")
if internet_okay:  # step 2
    do_other_stuff()  # step3
```

For further assistance here, check out [these directions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).